# How maths can help to compute convergence?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

$r'(\theta)^2 + r(\theta)^2 = \theta^2,\quad r(t=0)=0\tag{1}$

There is an interesting approach to prove that the solutions of the equation $(1)$ have power series representations of form
$r(\theta) = \pm \ \left(\frac{\theta^2}{2}-\frac{\theta^4}{32}+\frac{\theta^6}{768}+\cdots\right)$, and the power series convergence. ([More details](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/121402/what-is-symmetry-group-of-non-linear-equation)

However, I am still unable to compute the radius of convergence analytically.
Any areas of math to solve the problem?
Any help, thoughts are highly welcomed.

Comment: Doesn't @RobertBryant give all the relevant references in his very nice answer to the original question? (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/121402/what-is-symmetry-group-of-non-linear-equation)

Comment: @Igor Revin I understand that this is a nice prove, but what about the radius?

Comment: I don't know who this Igor Revin is, but as for @RobertBryant's proof, if you read it to the end, he gives a reference addressing the very question you asks.

Comment: @Igor Rivin. The reference just explains the power series convegence, but I cannot see that the radius is, I guess, 7/2?

Comment: I am not sure, but you asked "what kind of mathematics will give you a radius of convergence", and the answer is "the kind Robert refers to".

Comment: Well, the kind of mathematics can prove the convergence, but I cannot see any way to compute the radius of convergence. For eg how to prove it is 7/2?

Comment: Btw., the above are only the solutions for which $r''(0)$ exists (and then $r$ is analytical). Otherwise, you may also multiply with $\operatorname{sgn}(\theta)$ to obtain more solutions. I don't see any obstacle that prevents the existence of the *solution* for $\theta\to\infty$ (after all there is a nice physical interpretation in terms of energy; also Robert Bryan says so in his answer). There may be obstacles against convergence of the *series* somewhere in the complex, but I don't see where you guessed the $\frac 72$ from

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen. I cannot prove that radius of convergence is not equal 7/2 either. It's only numerical calculations result in 7/2.

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen. "after all there is a nice physical interpretation in terms of energy" - could you explain it in more details please?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you didn't get a satisfactory answer so far is that your problem is not a bona fide initial problem and cannot be turned into one using suitable substitutions and the like. When you introduce, e.g., a new independent variable $u$ by means of $t:=\sqrt{2u}$ you get an "initial value problem" of the form
$$\dot r(u)=\sqrt{1-{r^2(u)\over u}},\quad r(0)=0\ .$$
Changing the initial condition to $r(0)=10^{-100}$ lets the solution disappear, contrasting the case of "ordinary" IVP's, where the solutions depend continuously on the initial conditions.

Nevertheless, the solution you are interested in can be written as
$$r(t)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k t^{2k}\ ,$$
whereby the $a_k$ satisfy the following recursion:
$$a_1={1\over2},\quad a_n=-{1\over 4n}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a_k a_{n-k}+4\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}k(n+1-k)a_ka_{n+1-k}\right)\qquad(n\geq2)\ .$$ 
Using this recursion and putting $b_n:=|a_n|^{-1/2n}$ one obtains the following plot (note that $\lim\inf_{n\to\infty} b_n$ is the radius of convergence you are after):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [Cauchy-Hadamard theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem)?

Answer (score 0):

An asymptotic formula for the coefficients of the power series would help if explicit expression is not available. The derivation of the asymptotic approximation depends on the way you obtained that power series.